# Sum of second and third elements of a list of lists of Ints in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that takes a list of lists of Ints as input and returns a list of Int containing the sum of second and third elements of each list if the list contains at least 3 elements.

I get an error about non-exhaustive pattern with what I have and I don't know why.

```
sumSecondThird :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
sumSecondThird [] = []
sumSecondThird ((_:x:y:_):xs) = (x+y):(sumSecondThird xs)
```

I can make it work by using the `!!` function, but I want to use pattern matching. Any help on why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to compile with `-Wall` as it can often reveal potential sources of error:

```
Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘sumSecondThird’:
        Patterns not matched:
            [] : _
            [_] : _
            [_, _] : _
```

Your pattern match is still missing several possibilities, so whenever `sumSecondThird` encounters them it will fail with a run-time error.

To fix the solution, you need to handle the case for these missing patterns.  Since these patterns occur only if the list is shorter than 3 elements, you can simply ignore them and move on:

```hs
sumSecondThird :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
sumSecondThird [] = []
sumSecondThird ((_:x:y:_):xs) = (x+y):(sumSecondThird xs)
sumSecondThird (_:xs) = sumSecondThird xs
```

Comment: Would this be considered a primitive recursion? Because I forgot to mention that requirement.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what primitive recursion means in this context, but it should be because there's not much freedom in how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
sumSecondThird :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
sumSecondThird = foldr go [] where
  go (_:x:y:_) r = x + y : r
  go _         r = r
```